# How to check rotation of an object in Unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

I'm a unity3d learner. I have a problem with rotation of an object. I want to rotate objects about 40 degrees along the z axis. If the objects rotation has reached 40 degrees, I want something to happen. Here is my code.

```
foreach(Touch touch in Input.touches) {
    if(touch.phase != TouchPhase.Ended && touch.phase != TouchPhase.Canceled) {
        var target = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0,-40);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, target, Time.deltaTime * smooth);
        if (transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z == -40) {
            toggle = true;
            speech = "blah blah blah";
            snake = man;
        } 
    }   
}
```

The `if(transform.rotation.eulerAngles.z == -40)` line of code is not working. So I don't know if the rotation degree has reached 40 degree or not. How do I check if the rotation degree has reached 40 degrees?

Comment: If it is a float or a double the you shouldn't use == to check for equality because the value could be off by just a fraction. Try abs(z-(-40))<1.0e-6, where abs is the absolute value function and z is the angle. Also are you sure the angles are in degrees and not in radians?

Comment: I use degrees. But absolute function is not work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### *I don't understand your code intent.*

EulerAngles is not set negative only positive value(Vector3)
-if(eulerAngles.z == -40) is not work *you **try** change value -40 -> 320*

If you want scenario
 **ontouch -> object rotation -> event**
try this code.

```
float rotTime = 1f; // rotation duration
Vector3 rotValue = new Vector3(0, 0, -40f); // rotation value

void Update () {
    foreach (Touch touch in Input.touches)
        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) OnTouchEvent();
}

void OnTouchEvent()
{
    StopCoroutine("rotationCoroutine"); 
    StartCoroutine("rotationCoroutine");
}
IEnumerator rotationCoroutine()
{
    float startTime = Time.time;

    Vector3 startRot = transform.eulerAngles;
    Vector3 endRot = startRot;
    endRot += rotValue;

    while (Time.time - startTime <= rotTime)
    {
        transform.eulerAngles = Vector3.Slerp(startRot, endRot,(Time.time - startTime) / rotTime);
        yield return null; // wait 1 frame
    }
    //rotation end
    MyAction();
}

void MyAction()
{
    Debug.Log("rotation end");
    //toggle = true;
    //speech = "blah blah";
    //snake = man;
}
```

Good Luck :D